# How do I get the current time only in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

How can I get the current time in JavaScript and use it in a timepicker?

I tried `var x = Date()` and got:

> Tue May 15 2012 05:45:40 GMT-0500

But I need only current time, for example, `05:45`

How can I assign this to a variable?

Comment: @swati Because we want this to be our goto source for all our programming problems. Maybe somebody else has a better solution and this way they can all be listed as reference in one spot.

Comment: @swati - I know you wrote that comment over 3 years ago, but now this page is the #1 search result in Google for "get time part JavaScript". Keep in mind that today's question IS tomorrow's search results.

Comment: @DavidDeutsch This should be like a heading in bold on the Ask question page. 

"today's question IS tomorrow's search results"

Comment: to get current time simply: `new Date().toTimeString().split(' ')[0];`

Answer (score 306, accepted):

```
var d = new Date("2011-04-20T09:30:51.01");
d.getHours(); // => 9
d.getMinutes(); // =>  30
d.getSeconds(); // => 51
```

or

```
var d = new Date(); // for now
d.getHours(); // => 9
d.getMinutes(); // =>  30
d.getSeconds(); // => 51
```

Comment: `var d = new Date("2011-04-20 09:30:51.01");
alert(d.getHours()); // => 9`  output `NaN`

Comment: @Chinmay235 Added `T` so now it's the right universal iso. BTW I only see `undefined` in IE. Anyway Fixed.

Answer (score 236):

Short and simple:

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString(); // 11:18:48 AM
//---
new Date().toLocaleDateString(); // 11/16/2015
//---
new Date().toLocaleString(); // 11/16/2015, 11:18:48 PM
```

4 hours later (use milisec: sec==1000):

```
new Date(new Date().getTime() + 4*60*60*1000).toLocaleTimeString(); // 3:18:48 PM or 15:18:48
```

2 days before:

```
new Date(new Date().getTime() - 2*24*60*60*1000).toLocaleDateString() // 11/14/2015
```

Comment: The calculation of adding and subtracting is helpful!

Comment: What would I need to change it to if I wanted to add 1 minute instead?

Comment: This prints out "... GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)" in all the browsers I've been testing.... You may say it is something about my settings, but even then, I want to only show HH:MM:SS using ONE command (if any).

Comment: what to do if i not require A.M or P.M in last of time .

Answer (score 112):

### Get and set the current time efficiently using javascript

I couldn't find a solution that did exactly what I needed. I wanted clean and tiny code so I came up with this:

**PURE JAVASCRIPT**

```js
function timeNow(i) {
  var d = new Date(),
    h = (d.getHours()<10?'0':'') + d.getHours(),
    m = (d.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + d.getMinutes();
  i.value = h + ':' + m;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="timeNow(test1)" href="#">SET TIME</a>
<input id="test1" type="time" value="10:40" />
```

---

**UPDATE**

There is now sufficient browser support to simply use: `toLocaleTimeString`

For **html5** type `time` the format must be `hh:mm`.

```js
function timeNow(i) {
  i.value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
}
```

```html
<a onclick="timeNow(test1)" href="#">SET TIME</a>
<input id="test1" type="time" value="10:40" />
```

<kbd>[Try it on jsfiddle](http://cssdeck.com/labs/uzhgqsnm)</kbd>

Comment: @gcoleman0828 I was late to the party. Thanks for the vote :)

Comment: ...Did you typo 'get' as 'set'? If not, your answer doesn't match your title and your title doesn't match the question.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes My answer does both. The javascript gets the time and the html shows the user how the code can be used to set the time also if required. I have updated my answer to reflect that. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: the time is showing 30 minutes behind for me, if I click on Set time, it is correct but in military time . Set time should be toggle guess that doesnt work

Comment: The toLocaleTime will have a different format depending on the browser's locale, instead you can use a fixed locale without PM/AM like fr to get a time matching html5 time format `new Date().toLocaleTimeString('fr', {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});`

Answer (score 35):

You can simply use this methods.

[image]

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: "2-digit", hour12: false }));
console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: "2-digit" }));
```

Comment: One of the clean answer to the question

Answer (score 32):

Try

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replace("/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/", "$1");
```

Or

```
new Date().toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
```

Comment: In the second form if you use just toString() and change the 0 to a 4 you also get just the time in the format HH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 16):

```js
const date = Date().slice(16,21);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
new Date().toTimeString().slice(0, 8);
```

or

```
new Date().toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
```

It should work.

Comment: Quite easy and one of the good solution. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
function getCurrentTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var hh = date.getHours();
    var mm = date.getMinutes();

    hh = hh < 10 ? '0'+hh : hh; 
    mm = mm < 10 ? '0'+mm : mm;

    curr_time = hh+':'+mm;
    return curr_time;
}
```

Comment: If all you need is time without seconds and you don't need the PM or AM parts, the code above should work perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

This how you can do it.

```js
const date = new Date();
const time = date.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].split(':');
console.log(time[0] + ':' + time[1])
```

Comment: This is no less cryptic or any better than `new Date().toTimeString().slice(0, 5)`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu As a (primarily) Python dev I appreciate the cryptic one-liner you've provided and would not have scrolled far enough down the page to see Parmeet Singh's concise answer (to which I'm assuming you were referring). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

See these Date methods ...

- toLocaleTimeString - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString
- toTimeString - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString

Answer (score 3):

this -

```
var x = new Date(); 
var h = x.getHours(); 
var m = x.getMinutes(); 
var s = x.getSeconds();
```

so-

```
 x = date
h = hours
m = mins
s = seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this in ES6, in the format you requested (hh:mm), would be this way:

```js
const goodTime = `${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}`;

console.log(goodTime);
```

(Obviously, the console logging is not part of the solution)

Comment: How is this adding anything to the existing answers? The `console.log` is, as you already wrote, not really part of the solution so this this doesn't provide a new solution.

Comment: The other answers are excessively lengthy and contain deprecated techniques. My answer provides an accurate, clean answer. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: This doesn't work for times with single-digit hours or minutes

Answer (score 2):

#### Date.toLocaleTimeString() options

The `Date.toLocaleTimeString()` function can receive an `options` parameter to format the output

Some of the available options are these

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeStyle: "full" })   // 4:43:58 AM Pacific Standard Time
new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeStyle: "long" })   // 4:43:58 AM PST
new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeStyle: "medium" }) // 4:43:58 AM
new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeStyle: "short" })  // 4:43 AM
```

Or you can specify the representation of the `hour`, `minute`, and `second` with these values:

- `"numeric"` (e.g., 1)
- `"2-digit"` (e.g., 01)

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: "2-digit" }) 
// 04:43 AM
```

Or set the 12-hour time using `hour12: true` or `false`

For more details take a look at
Date.toLocaleTimeString() [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#parameters) and
Intl.DateTimeFormat() [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#options)

Answer (score 1):

```
var today = new Date();  //gets current date and time
var hour = today.getHours();         
var minute = today.getMinutes();
var second = today.getSeconds();
```

Comment: How is this adding anything to the existing answers? The core problem was the absence of `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple functions to get Date and Time separated and with compatible format with Time and Date HTML input

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var d         = new Date(date),
      month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
      day   = '' + d.getDate(),
      year  = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

function formatTime(date) {
        var hours   = new Date().getHours() > 9 ? new Date().getHours() : '0' + new Date().getHours()
        var minutes = new Date().getMinutes() > 9 ? new Date().getMinutes() : '0' + new Date().getMinutes()

        return hours + ':' + minutes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign to variables and display it.

```
time = new Date();

var hh = time.getHours();
var mm = time.getMinutes();
var ss = time.getSeconds() 

document.getElementById("time").value = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
```

Comment: Why assume this needs to be stored in a `time` element? OP asked for storing in a variable, and only for the hour and minute. `let time = Date().substr(16, 5)` does that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way.

```
var now = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(now)
```

Here is also a way through string manipulation that was not mentioned.

```
var now = new Date()
console.log(now.toString().substr(16,8))
```

Comment: The shortest is `Date().substr(16, 5)`. You don't need `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but this depends on what you get when you hit `Date()`:

```
Date().slice(16,-12)
```

Comment: This looks identical to an existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46599746/3294944

Comment: @stealththeninja: it's not identical. This dumps the second and timezone as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm doing this: (Hope it helps someone)
What I'm doing is validating the time that the user enters in the HTML time input is not in the past:

```
let inputTime = value; // from time input in html (06:29)

const splittedInputTime = inputTime.split(':');

let currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setHours(splittedInputTime[0]);
currentDate.setMinutes(splittedInputTime[1]);

const finalInputTime = currentDate.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];

const currentTime = new Date().toTimeString().split(" ")[0];

// Returns a boolean (true/ false)
let validTime = finalInputTime >= currentTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getTime() {
      let today = new Date();
      let h = today.getHours();
      let m = today.getMinutes();
      let s = today.getSeconds();
      h = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h;
      m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
      s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;
      let time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
      return time;
    },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
let date = Date().slice(16,21);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
        console.log(strTime);
        $scope.time = strTime;

        date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
        month = '' + (date.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + date.getDate(1),
        year = date.getFullYear();
        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
        var tomorrow = [year, month, day].join('-');
        $scope.tomorrow = tomorrow;
```