# how to Code the first line of an if statement that tests whether the clock is at an hour on the dot

Tags: javascript, time

I'm very new to programming. I have a question about JavaScript. This is the one. "Code the first line of an if statement that tests whether the clock is at an hour on the dot. Check minutes and then seconds. Ignore milliseconds".. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getMinutes` `getSeconds` ... [MDN Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score -2):

Seems like a homework problem so I don't want to give you the answer, but I'll point you in the direction.

Javascript has a Date object which has functions for getting the minute, second, day, hour, etc. pieces of a datetime.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Answer (score -2):

Great You decided learning programming. But beginning is lot about reading:

A starting point could be https://stackoverflow.com/a/10599188/4415884

Also interesting to read is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

**Edit:** If You're really really new to programming, a quick course to the if statement may useful too: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

**Edit 2:** Fix links

Comment: Additionally: No. I'll not quickly code that for you. Because then You would not learn that much. Therefore hans on :)

Comment: "check hours, minutes, seconds"? That's what she said..I also don't know. Got from the book I'm studing.."A smarter way to learn java script" By Mark mayers. Thanks a lot @ hiddenAlpha

Comment: Seriously I didn't clicked the voting button..still don't know how this things working.@hiddenAlpha