# Javascript Timestamp to User localzone

Tags: javascript

I want to convert my timestamps to the users local time.

I know that i get the localzone with that

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

But i dont know how to calculate that with my timestamp to the localtime of the user...

I have the timestamp from that function

```
function time() {
    return parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000);
}
```

i get that `1544020722` timestamp and want not the hours and minutes of it but i want it in the local time of the user in javascript

offset give me only -60 but i dont know how to calculate that with my timestamp i have to show the user the correct time :/

I also doesnt find a function where i can easy "send" my timestamp and it gives back the current time for the localtime user

The best way is, if someone has a function where ich can easy convert that like

```
toUsersLocaltime(1544020722)
```

or something.

Thanks for your help

Comment: since the `timeZoneOffset` is in minutes, can't you just multiply it by 60 and subtract from the timestamp you've previously calculated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current time only in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599148/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-only-in-javascript)