# How to get current date and time printed using reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, kendo-react-ui

I am trying to create a small program where I have to display date and time using react JS. It is displaying everything as expected except date and time value in the HTML page.

```
enter code here
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const name = "Flash";
const currDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString;
const currTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString;

ReactDOM.render(
<>
<h1>My name is {name}</h1>
<p> Current Date is = {currDate} </p>
<p> Curremt Time is = {currTime} </p> 
</>,
document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599148/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-only-in-javascript

Comment: Please clarify the actual result versus what you are expecting. It is displaying null, undefined, some other result you were not expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is perfect in your code, but you just forgot to run these functions.

`toLocaleDateString` and `toLocaleTimeString` are functions not just objects so you need to add parenthesis to run these functions and get the results.

so replace this:

```
const currDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString;
const currTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString;
```

with this:-

```
const currDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
const currTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
```

---

So your final code becomes this:-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const name = "Flash";
const currDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
const currTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

ReactDOM.render(
<>
<h1>My name is {name}</h1>
<p> Current Date is = {currDate} </p>
<p> Curremt Time is = {currTime} </p> 
</>,
document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Hi Kashan, This worked for me. Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

A simple step by step guide to get current date in Reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  state={
    curTime : new Date().toLocaleString(),
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Current Time : {this.state.curTime}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```