# Only get time from string

Tags: javascript

This is some code I got from another overflow post:

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+dt.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
var offset = -300; //Timezone offset for EST in minutes.
var estDate = new Date(dt.getTime() + offset*60*1000);
console.log(estDate);
```

It returns:
`Wed Jul 29 2020 10:40:40 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

How would I JUST get the time, so 10:40. **I am trying to get EST TIME.**

Comment: `+dt.getTimezoneOffset()601000` <-- ??

Comment: Why did you take that code? Do you even understand it? Seems to me a little bit random to just take any code..

Comment: Use getHours getMinutes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current time only in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599148/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-only-in-javascript)

Comment: dt.getHours()+":"+dt.getMinutes()

Comment: I am trying to get the EST time, these do not provide the time in EST.

Comment: @Bee You already have the EST time in `estDate` don't you? Just use `estDate.getHours() + ':' + estDate.getMinutes()` and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var dt = new Date();
dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+dt.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);

console.log(dt.getHours()+":"+dt.getMinutes());
```

Comment: let offset = -5.0

let clientDate = new Date();
let utc = clientDate.getTime() + (clientDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

let serverDate = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset));
console.log(serverDate.getHours()+":"+serverDate.getMinutes());