# How to extract time from toUTCString()

Tags: javascript

I have tried to get current PST time through javaScript.

```
  var offset = 420; 
  var offsetMillis = offset * 60 * 1000;
  var today = new Date();
  var millis = today.getTime();
  var timeZoneOffset = (today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
  var pst = millis - offsetMillis; 
  var currentDate = new Date(pst);
  var pt_date = currentDate.toUTCString();
  console.log(pt_date) //Mon, 21 Sep 2020 02:52:04 GMT
```

I would like to extract time from pt_date.
My Expected output is

> 'Monday 08:22 AM' ie:'EEEE hh:mm a'

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599148/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-only-in-javascript/25164024

Comment: then why are you outputting that as a UTCString?

Comment: when calling UTCstring im getting exact PST date. @Berto99

Comment: Is there any other way to find current PST time

Comment: PST in respect to GMT is `-8:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 let offset = 420; 
  let offsetMillis = offset * 60 * 1000;
  let today = new Date();
  let millis = today.getTime();
  let timeZoneOffset = (today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
  let pst = millis - offsetMillis; 
  let currentDate = new Date(pst);
let d = new Date(currentDate);

let days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

console.log(days[d.getDay()] + ' '+  d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' +  d.getSeconds() + ' '+ formatAMPM(d))


function formatAMPM(date) {
  let hours = date.getHours();
  let minutes = date.getMinutes();
  let ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  return ampm;
  }
```