# get time format to hh:mm

Tags: javascript, time, fetch

I fetch a specific time from an JSON. The value I get for the start-time looks like this: **2021-02-15T20:30:00+01:00**
But I need to get it in hh:mm.
I tried Date.parse() but I am unable to get the hours and minutes from this value.
How can I do this else?

```
fetch('XXX')
        .then(Response => Response.json())
        .then(data => { 

    var summary = data['items']['0']['summary'];
    var location = data['items']['0']['location'];
    var start = data['items']['0']['start']['dateTime'];
    var end = data['items']['0']['end']['dateTime'];
```

Comment: Where is your `Date.parse()` code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current time only in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599148/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-only-in-javascript)

Comment: The above assumes you've parsed the value as a `Date` object. Given the format you've shown, that's as easy as `var end = new Date(data['items']['0']['end']['dateTime']);`

Comment: const parsed = Date.parse(start);
console.log(parsed);

Comment: See the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always liked this method for simplicity.

```js
let time = new Date();
console.log(time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second:'numeric', hour12: true }));  
console.log(time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true }));  
console.log(time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'}));  
console.log(time.toLocaleString('en-US', {second: 'numeric'}));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```js
const date = new Date("2021-02-15T20:30:00+01:00");
const formatted = `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`;

console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `getMinutes` and `getHours` isn't a great solution because it doesn't guarantee that values less than 10 are padded. You are better off doing string manipulation. Destructuring arrays can make this a lot easier to follow.

```
const dt = "2021-02-15T20:30:00+01:00";
const [date, time] = dt.split("T")
const [hours, minutes] = time.split(":")
const t = hours + ":" + minutes
'20:30'
```

Had the input datetime been `2021-02-15T01:02:00+01:00` then using getHours and getMinutes would have produced `1:2` which is not the expected time format