# I only want to get the time in my time zone

Tags: javascript, typescript

The variable timezone contains the following values.
I want to get only the time.
Please let me know if anyone knows how to do this.

```
console(timezone)
// Thu Jan 01 1970 09:00:00 GMT+0900
```

Comment: what is **timezone** variable  ?

Comment: Look at this, it might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599148/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-only-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If **timezone** is just a string . You can apply this logic :

```js
const timezone = "Thu Jan 01 1970 09:00:00 GMT+0900"

const time = timezone.split(' ')[4].split('').slice(1, 5).join('')

console.log(time)
```

Comment: I would like to display 9:00 instead of 09:00:00

Comment: I updated the snippet